# How to implement `git diff --raw` with jGit?

Tags: git, jgit

Is there any example of (if possible) how to implement `git diff --raw` using jGit?

Comment: The `DiffCommand` in JGit uses `DiffFormatter` to format and write the diff into output stream. Such formatter does not contain method to set format to "raw"—I think you need to implement your own `DiffCommand` and `DiffFormatter`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to get it working.

https://gist.github.com/robisonsantos/7a35b79c86eedb58a31402d3ffca63f6

I was not able to make git create a "COPY" or "RENAME" change to validate the `score` it returns, but the code produces the expected output.

I didn't have to implement a `DiffFormatter` as I was able to get the data I want from the `DiffEntry` class.